# Why my carousel caption animation is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set animation to bootstrap carousel caption. But I am not getting.
Here is my code index.html

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="MatajerWebSite.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/style.js"></script>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<%--<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();
    });
</script>--%>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container main-container">

        <h1>Bootstrap Carousel with Animate.css</h1>
        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <!-- First slide -->
                <div class="item active deepskyblue">

                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInLeft">This is the caption for slide 1
                        </h3>
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInRight">This is the caption for slide 1
                        </h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated zoomInUp">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.item -->

                <!-- Second slide -->
                <div class="item skyblue">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 class="icon-container" data-animation="animated bounceInDown">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
                        </h3>
                        <h3 data-animation="animated bounceInUp">This is the caption for slide 2
                        </h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated zoomInRight">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.item -->

                <!-- Third slide -->
                <div class="item darkerskyblue">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3 class="icon-container" data-animation="animated zoomInLeft">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>
                        </h3>
                        <h3 data-animation="animated flipInX">This is the caption for slide 3
                        </h3>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-animation="animated lightSpeedIn">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.item -->

            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel-inner -->

            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <p class="p">Demo by Antonietta Perna. <a href="http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations" target="_blank">See article</a>.</p>
</form>
```

style.js

```
/* Demo Scripts for Bootstrap Carousel and Animate.css article
* on SitePoint by Maria Antonietta Perna
*/
(function( $ ) {

//Function to animate slider captions 
function doAnimations( elems ) {
    //Cache the animationend event in a variable
    var animEndEv = 'webkitAnimationEnd animationend';

    elems.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $animationType = $this.data('animation');
        $this.addClass($animationType).one(animEndEv, function () {
            $this.removeClass($animationType);
        });
    });
}

//Variables on page load 
var $myCarousel = $('#carousel-example-generic'),
    $firstAnimatingElems = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");

//Initialize carousel 
$myCarousel.carousel();

//Animate captions in first slide on page load 
doAnimations($firstAnimatingElems);

//Pause carousel  
$myCarousel.carousel('pause');


//Other slides to be animated on carousel slide event 
$myCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var $animatingElems = $(e.relatedTarget).find("[data-animation ^= 'animated']");
    doAnimations($animatingElems);
});  

 })(jQuery);
```

style.css file

```
 .main-container {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
.skyblue {
    background-color: #22c8ff;
}
.deepskyblue {
    background-color: #00bfff;
}
.darkerskyblue {
    background-color: #00a6dd;
}
.carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 0;
}
.carousel-control.right,
.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: none;
}
.carousel .item {
    min-height: 350px; 
    height: 100%;
    width:100%; 
}
.carousel-caption h3,
.carousel .icon-container,
.carousel-caption button {
    background-color: #09c;
}
.carousel-caption h3 {
    padding: .5em;
}
.carousel .icon-container {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.carousel-caption button {
    border-color: #00bfff;
    margin-top: 1em; 
}

/* Animation delays */
.carousel-caption h3:first-child {
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
.carousel-caption h3:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.carousel-caption button {
    animation-delay: 3s;
}  

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.p {
  padding-top: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

.p a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

this is my complete code. I got error like below

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065 source: http://localhost:49905/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you a fairly clear indication of the problem.

You are referencing glyphicons but the font has failed to load. Check the browser console for any other information and then correct the HTML to make sure it is loaded.

Comment: that is the only one error message appear in console

Comment: I went to the [URL](http://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations) shown at the bottom of the HTML in your question and downloaded the example files. The demo works for me, perhaps you should go through your code and see where you have deviated from the demo.